# Why Go channels limit the buffer size

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am new to Go and I might be missing the point but why are Go channels limited in the maximum buffer size buffered channels can have?  For example if I make a channel like so

```
channel := make(chan int, 100)
```

I cannot add more than 100 elements to the channel without blocking, is there a reason for this?  Further they cannot dynamically be resized, because the channel API does not support that.

This seems sort of limiting in the language's support for universal synchronization with a single mechanism since it lacks convenience compared to an unbounded semaphore.  For example a generalized semaphore's value can be increased without bounds.

Comment: This is such a reasonable and commonplace thing that it is no surprise Go doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 25):

If one component of a program can't keep up with its input, it needs to put back-pressure on the rest of the system, rather than letting it run ahead and generate gigabytes of data that will never get processed because the system ran out of memory and crashed.

There is really no such thing as an unlimited buffer, because machines have limits on what they can handle. Go requires you to specify a size for buffered channels so that you will think about what size buffer your program actually needs and can handle. If it really needs a billion items, and can handle them, you can create a channel that big. But in most cases a buffer size of 0 or 1 is actually what is needed.

Comment: As you said one limitation is the RAM of the hardware. But the number of elements in the channel does not give a good approximation of its total memory usage when the elements have variable sizes, like strings. Using the number of elements as limit is an implementation choice that works in some cases, but I think it lacks flexibility.

Comment: "If it really needs a billion items, and can handle them, you can create a channel that big" This makes no sense. This is basically saying "if your browser can support 4GB of memory for a webpage, you should allocate 4GB of memory for every webpage whether it uses it or not".

Comment: You forgot to translate my first "if"—"If it really needs a billion items".

Answer (score 3):

This is because Channels are designed for efficient communication between concurrent goroutines, but the need you have is something different: the fact you are blocking denotes that the recipient is not attending the work queue, and "dynamic" is rarely free.

There are a variety of different patterns and algorithms you can use to solve the problem you have: you could change your channel to accept arrays of ints, you could add additional goroutines to better balance or filter work. Or you could implement your own dynamic channel. Doing so is certainly a useful exercise for seeing why dynamic channels aren't a great way to build concurrency.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func dynamicChannel(initial int) (chan <- interface{}, <- chan interface{}) {
    in := make(chan interface{}, initial)
    out := make(chan interface{}, initial)
    go func () {
        defer close(out)
        buffer := make([]interface{}, 0, initial)
    loop:
        for {
            packet, ok := <- in
            if !ok {
                break loop
            }
            select {
            case out <- packet:
                continue
            default:
            }
            buffer = append(buffer, packet)
            for len(buffer) > 0 {
                select {
                case packet, ok := <-in:
                    if !ok {
                        break loop
                    }
                    buffer = append(buffer, packet)

                case out <- buffer[0]:
                    buffer = buffer[1:]
                }
            }
        }
        for len(buffer) > 0 {
            out <- buffer[0]
            buffer = buffer[1:]
        }
    } ()

    return in, out
}


func main() {
    in, out := dynamicChannel(4)

    in <- 10
    fmt.Println(<-out)

    in <- 20
    in <- 30

    fmt.Println(<-out)
    fmt.Println(<-out)

    for i := 100; i < 120; i++ {
        in <- i
    }
    fmt.Println("queued 100-120")
    fmt.Println(<-out)
    close(in)
    fmt.Println("in closed")
    for i := range out {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Generally, if you are blocking, it indicates your concurrency is not well balanced. Consider a different strategy. For example, a simple tool to look for files with a matching .checksum file and then check the hashes:

```
func crawl(toplevel string, workQ chan <- string) {
  defer close(workQ)
  for _, path := filepath.Walk(toplevel, func (path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err == nil && info.Mode().IsRegular() {
      workQ <- path
  }
}

// if a file has a .checksum file, compare it with the file's checksum.
func validateWorker(workQ <- chan string) {
  for path := range workQ {
    // If there's a .checksum file, read it, limit to 256 bytes.
    expectedSum, err := os.ReadFile(path + ".checksum")[:256]
    if err != nil {  // ignore
      continue
    }
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
      continue
    }
    defer close(file)
    hash := sha256.New()
    if _, err := io.Copy(hash, file); err != nil {
      log.Printf("couldn't hash %s: %w", path, err)
      continue
    }
    actualSum := fmt.Sprintf("%x", hash.Sum(nil))
    if actualSum != expectedSum {
      log.Printf("%s: mismatch: expected %s, got %s", path, expectedSum, actualSum)
  }
}
```

Even without any .checksum files, the crawl function will tend to outpace the worker queue. When .checksum files are encountered, especially if the files are large, the worker could take much, much longer to perform a single checksum.

A better aim here would be to achieve more consistent throughput by reducing the number of things the "validateWorker" does. Right now it is sometimes fast, because it checks for the checksum file. Othertimes it is slow, because it also loads has to read and checksum the files.

```
type ChecksumQuery struct {
  Filepath  string
  ExpectSum string
}

func crawl(toplevel string, workQ chan <- ChecksumQuery) {
  // Have a worker filter out files which don't have .checksums, and allow it
  // to get a little ahead of the crawl function.
  checkupQ := make(chan string, 4)

  go func () {
    defer close(workQ)
    for path := range checkupQ {
      expected, err := os.ReadFile(path + ".checksum")[:256]
      if err == nil && len(expected) > 0 {
        workQ <- ChecksumQuery{ path, string(expected) }
      }
    }
  }()

  go func () {
    defer close(checkupQ)
    for _, path := filepath.Walk(toplevel, func (path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
      if err == nil && info.Mode().IsRegular() {
        checkupQ <- path
      }
    }
  }()
}
```

Run a suitable number of validate workers, assign the workQ a suitable size, but if the crawler or validate functions block, it is because validate is doing useful work.

If your validate workers are all busy, they are all consuming large files from disk and hashing them. Having other workers interrupt this by crawling for more filenames, allocating and passing strings, isn't advantageous.

Other scenarios might be passing large lists to workers, in which pass the slices over channels (its cheap); or dynamic sized groups of things, in which case consider passing channels or captures over channels.

Answer (score -5):

The buffer size is the number of elements that can be sent to the channel without the send blocking. By default, a channel has a buffer size of 0 (you get this with make(chan int)). This means that every single send will block until another goroutine receives from the channel. A channel of buffer size 1 can hold 1 element until sending blocks, so you'd get

```
c := make(chan int, 1)
c <- 1 // doesn't block
c <- 2 // blocks until another goroutine receives from the channel
```

I suggest you to look this for more clarification:
 https://rogpeppe.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/unlimited-buffering-with-low-overhead/
 http://openmymind.net/Introduction-To-Go-Buffered-Channels/

Comment: I understand how buffered channels work. My question was more on the lines of why they were designed to have a limited buffer as opposed to a dynamically sized buffer. IMO It makes more sense to let them hold unlimited values without blocking if using buffered channels

Comment: @Curious Because it is a _buffer_. **Buffer: “a temporary memory area in which data is stored while it is being processed or transferred.”** And what’s the point of having buffers? To slow down, to “buffer” the inputs, because otherwise inputs could be given more than it can process within a certain period of time!